# Как отсортировать элемент массива по элементу строки на php?

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Есть массив вида

```
$array = array('1211,1433,5454,4343','1211,1433,5454,5443','1211,1433,5454,1143');
```

Как его отсортировать по убыванию по числу после последней запятой?

То есть 4343,5443,1143?

Эти числа могут быть одинаковыми в некоторых строках.

Comment: У вас в массиве строки. Вы хотите отсортировать числа внтури этих строк? Тогда explode, потом sort, потом implode вам помогут

Comment: @АлексейШиманский тогда я вообще ничего не понял из данного условия

Comment: нормальное учебное задание

Comment: Есть еще 1 условие-эти числа могут повторяться в разных элементах массива.

Answer (score 0):

Для сортировки можно использовать функцию **[usort](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php)** - Сортирует массив по значениям используя пользовательскую функцию для сравнения элементов

Для нахождения последнего элемента в строке можно использовать **[strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php)** у которого для `offset` задавать отрицательное значение.

Собственно это всё, что нужно.

1. Используем usort
2. Для каждого сравниваемого значения (`a` и `b`) находим вхождение последней запятой
3. Берём подстроку (от последней запятой) с помощью **[substr](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php)** и переводим его в число (например через **[intval](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.intval.php)**)
4. Теперь осталось только сравнить эти числа и вернуть нужный результат из функции usort на основе сранвния